ASP.NET Core 8 Integration test configuration using WebApplicationFactory
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 application and a set of integration tests. I have recently added Azure App Config to the project, but when the application is run from the integration tests using a WebApplicationFactory<Program> I want the app to get configuration values from a appsettings.test.json file instead of Azure.
It seems the standard approach to overriding the application configuration/services is to create a class that derives from WebApplicationFactory<Program> and override ConfigureWebHost() where you can call methods like builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration() where I can call configuration.Sources.Clear() to clear existing config sources then configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json");
The issue with this approach is that it adds Azure Config as per a normal start up first, meaning:

It makes it slow as it needs to connect, and
From the CI/CD pipeline I don't have credentials to authenticate with Azure so it will fail anyway.

What is the approach so I can just specify the config outright for a test context without trying to remove what's already been setup?

Usually you can tune services for tests by calling builder.ConfigureTestServices() in ConfigureWebHost() called in class derived from WebApplicationFactory<Program> like for configuring EF Context options. But when your (or third party's) services are executed as soon as you add them to service collection, then the only way to configure them is through configuration, as configuration sources can be modified before setting up DI container. You don't have to remove Azure configuration source, you can override its values with new source containing a bool flag disabling stuff you don't want.

there is no need to add configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json") in ConfigureWebHost for the WebApplicationFactory to pick up specific appsettings file. All you need to do is set the correct Environment in the ConfigureWebHost method that you are overriding.
So in your case you just need to do following. Don't forget that the test json file has to be in same folder as is the application you are testing and not in the test project:
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
  builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
  {
  }).UseEnvironment("test");
}

